# Domain Model for Remote devices

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, solid-principles

I'm looking for design advice for a domain model scenario I have.

Let's say I have have a squad of Robots, each controllable via a wireless network connection.

I have an IRobot domain object that represents a real-world robot. The interface looks like so:

```
public interface IRobot
{
    void MoveHeadUp(int toAngle);
    void MoveHeadDown(int toAngle);
    int GetHeadAngle();
}
```

Example scenario: A virtual robot is shown in a GUI. In offline mode, the GUI shows what would happen if we tell the domain object (IRobot) to raise its head 5 degrees.

In online mode, the GUI would show the robot move AND the command would be sent to the physical robot and it would move as well.

I'm trying to add remote capabilities around this domain object, ie. getting/setting remote state via Ethernet or serial, etc. I don't want to pollute the domain object with network connectivity issues.

What is the best approach to implement IRobot domain behaviour and keep remote connection implementation details separate?

Comment: I'm not sure DDD is the best fit for this. It's best used for collaborative domains where business processes are initiated by humans. You will get a lot of rigidity from DDD and few of its benefits IMO.

Comment: this is an interesting question. i'll keep following it...
@guillaume31 is that so different than updating a DB?
i can see some similarity of using Active Record where the object talk directly to the DB / IRobot against using DDD where the domain model acts like the actual robot and validates all the actions before submitting them to the real robot

Comment: Not sure about DDD for communication.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't suggesting DDD for communication :)  I want to model the domain behaviour and separate the communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this is messaging.

All of your commands (and that's what you're giving your robots), could be efficiently communicated over whatever you need (transport of your choice) and your robot (virtual or physical) would receive the command and act on it.

You can think of these robots as endpoints. Each endpoint has a name/address. You're dispatching a command to those robots and it's no longer your concern how on the robot (physical or emulated) command is executed.

You have mentioned

> In online mode

Does that mean you also have an offline mode? If so, I'd look into messaging for sure.

Comment: I also considered the message bus approach, which is starting to make more sense as we flesh out the design. Thank you for the assistance!